# Why is $e^{i\hat{p}L/\hbar}$ only an operator when it is outside an integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, fourier-transform

[image: Snippet from Pg. 68 of "Quantum Paradoxes: Quantum Theory for the Perplexed by Y. Aharonov and D. Rohrlich]

Looking at the screenshot provided below, which is an excerpt from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527403914) textbook, really nothing more than a derivation of momentum as the generator of translations, would someone be kind enough to explain why "$p$ is an operator only outside the integral" as he says? It's not clear to me that this should be true. What about the act of integration is turning $p$ from an operator into a variable?

Comment: Hmm, I think the real answer to your question is that if you're trying to learn QM, you should toss away this book and get a standard introductory textbook. The inconsistent notation and sloppy explanations in the excerpt are unfortunately very common when professors write books that aren't vetted by students. Once you get a solid foundation from a different book, you can come back to this one and the answers will obvious!

Comment: @knzhou It's absolutely possible that I'm missing something obvious here, and I'll probably be embarrassed when I see what it is, but I would still appreciate if you could try to explain.

Comment: I agree with @knzhou, and would like to take the opportunity to suggest the book by Cohen-Tannoudji, it is great for someone who's getting started. I first learned QM there.

Comment: @Gold thank you. I certainly have a lot to learn, and when it comes to rigorous proofs and derivations like this I'm probably significantly closer to beginning than finishing -- *but*, I've been studying QM for long enough that it feels to me that I should have come across the explanation for this which makes me think its less about my not having any foundation in the topic and moreso either a blindspot or something I'm stupidly missing or forgetting that would make this clear. Could you offer a brief explanation?

Comment: @Gold  I can see that if it were simply $\hat{p}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}dp$ that this would clearly evaluate to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p\tilde{f}(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}dp$ where $p$ has become a variable. I assume that the answer is some simple generalization of this fact but I'm not seeing that its *necessarily* the case.

Comment: @CodyPayne I'm finishing to write one answer with the full details, but in any case it is exactly what you are guessing. It is a matter of how we define functions of operators. If $P$ is a Hermitian operator with basis $|p\rangle$ and $F(p)$ is some function, we define the function of the operator by its action on the basis as $$F(P)|p\rangle= F(p)|p\rangle.$$ This is the extension of what you said for the operator $P$ itself, and is in fact, the *definition* of the function applied to the operator.

Comment: @Gold thank you very much for your answer(s). It turns out what I was missing is that for any (presumably well-behaved) function $F$ on an operator $\hat{p}$ it is true that $F(\hat{p})|p\rangle=F(p)|p\rangle$. I'd either forgotten or somehow missed learning in the first place.

Comment: This is something that goes by the name of Borel functional calculus. It is the *definition* of functions of operators. In any case, even if this question has been solved, I advise to pick a book like Cohen-Tannoudji simply because you will learn a lot more and will probably find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on is that you have one operator which is diagonal in one particular basis. So to act with it on some vector, you expand the vector on the basis, and act with it on each term.

Very explicitly, and using a finite basis first to make the point. Let us suppose that you have a vector space $V$ and one operator $T$ which has the property that it has one basis of eigenvectors, i.e., one basis $\{e_i\}\subset V$ such that $$Te_i=\lambda_i e_i\tag{1}.$$

In that case if you want to act with $T$ on some generic $v$, the way to go is to expand $v$ in the basis and use linearity of $T$:

$$Tv=T\sum_{i=1}^n v^ie_i=\sum_{i=1}^n v^i Te_i=\sum_{i=1}^n v^i\lambda_i e_i\tag{2}.$$

In particular this is good to define functions of operators. If you have a function $F(x)$ and you want to define $F(T)$ it is immediate to do so in the basis of eigenvectors of $T$. You define the action on the basis by $$F(T)e_i=F(\lambda_i)e_i\tag{3}$$
and extend the action by linearity. In other words, $F(T)$ is *defined* by: $$F(T)v=F(T)\sum_{i=1}^n v^ie_i = \sum_{i=1}^n v^i F(T)e_i = \sum_{i=1}^n v^i F(\lambda_i)e_i.\tag{4}$$

Now, what you have is the "continuous basis" version of that. You are describing the states of your system in the position representation by position space wavefunctions $f(x)$. In that space, the momentum operator $P$ acts by differentiation,

$$Pf(x)=-i\hbar \dfrac{d}{dx}f\tag{5}.$$

You want to define a particular function of $P$, namely $e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}$. To do so, you want to use the basis of eigenstates of $P$. This means you must solve $$P\psi_p(x)=-i\hbar \dfrac{d}{dx}\psi_p(x)=p\psi_p(x)\tag{6}.$$

This gives you the exponentials $\psi_p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}x}$. This is a basis of eigenstates of $P$, the analogue $e_i$ appearing in (1). You can now define your desired exponential using the analogue of (3):

$$e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}\psi_p(x)=e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}p}\psi_p(x)\tag{7}$$

and extension by linearity. But beware that now linear combinations are taken with integrals since we are working with a continuous basis. In that case, expanding $f(x)$ on the basis and using the definition of $e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}$ we have $$e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}f(x)=e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}\int dp \tilde{f}(p)\psi_p(x)=\int dp \tilde{f}(p)e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}\psi_p(x)=\int dp e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}p}\tilde{f}(p)\psi_p(x)\tag{8}.$$

So you see that in the end this is, in fact, the *definition* of $e^{i\frac{L}{\hbar}P}$ on the position representation: it acts diagonally on the basis and is extended by linearity. This is the continuous version of (4) and is nothing but a definition.